# Apache Basic Auth and Mono

Tags: asp.net, apache, mono, basic-authentication

I have an existing aspx application running through mono on apache.
Apache is configured for basic auth and this is working correctly.

Now I want to be able to discover the username from within the aspx application.

What changes do I need to make to the web.config and what property should I access to get the name of the current user?